# Why is an injective holomorphism on $\mathbb C$ biholomophic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I heard this fact in a lecture I watched on Riemann surfaces, but I don't understand why it's true. Any literature on this would also be helpful.

Thanks,

James

Comment: - By holomorphism do you mean a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that is a holomorphic map?

Comment: I'm not sure what a ring homomorphism is. By holomorphism, I mean a function that is holomorphic (i.e. complex differentiable) and by biholomorphism, I mean a function that is holomorphic and that has a holomorphic inverse.

Comment: it comes from the local structure of holomorphic functions: if $f$ is holomorphic around $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)=0$ then $f$ is not injective around $z_0$, because (supposing $z_0=f(z_0)=0$ for simplicity) $f(z)=(g(z))^n$ for some holomorphic $g$, $g'(0)\neq 0$, $n$ smallest power in the Taylor series of $f$

Comment: Isn't $z^2$ entire?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY, sorry it was my typo. I meant this :

Comment: It is true that every **INJECTIVE** entire function is linear, that is : $f(z)=az+b$, where $a\neq0$. And so surjective.

@James I meant this.

Comment: Its prove is super beautiful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It comes from the local structure of holomorphic functions: if $f$ is holomorphic around $z_0$ and $f'(z_0)=0$ then $f$ is not injective around $z_0$, because (supposing $z_0=f(z_0)=0$ for simplicity) $f(z)=(g(z))^n$ for some holomorphic $g$, $g'(0)\neq 0$, $n$ smallest power in the Taylor series of $f$ --  [user8268](/users/8268/user8268)

Therefore, an injective holomorphic function has nonvanishing derivative, which by the inverse function theorem guarantees the smoothness of its inverse; the Cauchy-Riemann equations for the inverse can be checked directly. All this computation can be done on domains in $\mathbb C$; the conclusion directly transfers to the manifold case since the issue (regularity of the inverse) is *local*.